# show more, show less using ng-hide/ ng-show and function

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Because of the way I am implementing the show more/ show less feature, I am not sure if achieve the smooth effect is possible, but I thought it was worth ask in this forum and hope to receive some good ideas on making the effect possible.

I have a list of dynamic links that have a fixed limit number of 5, on ng-click the number gets increased and based on that rule the ng-hide/ ng-show sections are hidden or displayed.

What I would like to achieve is a smooth speed when the show more or show less links are clicked so the effect is not as fast and yes more elegant.

links mark-up:

```
<ul class="precall-journal-links">

    <li ng-repeat="fact in pc.historyRecords | limitTo:pc.limit" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 5px 0;">

        <a style="color: #345bab;" ng-click="pc.load_history_record(fact.dump.PreCallID); ">{{fact.dump.PrimaryKeyName}}:{{fact.dump.PreCallID}}
            _Date:{{fact.dump.MeetingDate}}
            _Time:{{fact.dump.MeetingTime}}
            _Location:{{fact.dump.MeetingLocation}}
        </a>

    </li>

</ul>
```

show more/ shoe less mark-up:

```
<div class="arrows" style="position: relative; top: 2px; left: 40px;">

    <div ng-hide="pc.historyRecords.length <= pc.limit">
        <a style="position: relative; bottom: 5px; color: #3e4c67;" ng-click="pc.increaseItemCount()">See More <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div ng-hide="(pc.limit === 5)||(pc.historyRecords.length <= 5)">
        <a style="position: relative; bottom: 5px; color: #3e4c67;" ng-click="pc.decreaseItemCount()">See Less <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

javascript to increase/ decrease limit:

```
vm.limit = 5;
vm.increaseItemCount = function (item) {
    vm.limit = vm.limit + 5;
};
vm.decreaseItemCount = function (item) {
    if (vm.limit > 0) {
        vm.limit = vm.limit - 5;
    }
};
```

Comment: you need first to decide what animation you want, read about angular fade in animations, etc. try smth and then ask a question

Comment: use **.ng-hide,.fade.ng-hide-remove, .fade.ng-hide-add** class

Comment: I want to use a slide down/ up effect same as what currently happens, but with a smooth transition.

Comment: @Sandeep, would you be able to show me how to us the directives you mentioned? Thank you

Comment: see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow. I think you understand clearly when you read this doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use an additional library like ngAnimate, you can add the css transitions yourself:

```
transition: ease .300s;
```

check this out: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)?

Take a look, I think thats exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: do I need to install an additional script to use ngAnimate? Thank you.